# The environment variables are not being reloaded after changing env values

Tags: django, django-environ

```
# settings.py
import environ
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False),)

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
environ.Env.read_env(env_file=f"{BASE_DIR}/.env")

DEFAULT_OTP = int(env("DEFAULT_OTP"))
```

```
# .env
DEFAULT_OTP=2951
```

Even after updating the value of DEFAULT_OTP to 2952, the Django project is still fetching the old value.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Yes, restarted several times.

Comment: Try this on debug console or somewhere as a test `print(f"Env file path: {BASE_DIR}/.env")` and check what path you get.

Comment: `Env file path: D:\Projects\project/.env`
The path `.env` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved after reinstalling the virtual environment. Many thanks to all of you.